# Random Number guessing game with 2 option menu

Tags: python-3.x, random

I am writing a random number generator that prompts the user for a guess. I want the program to only terminate when option 2 is chosen. So far all of my outputs are correct but when they get the guess right, it just jumps straight into a new game. It will not give the desired output. I am sure I am just overlooking a small detail in the while loop but I have tried what I am familiar with. Any help would be great. Below is what I have so far:

'''

```
# Import the Random function.
import random

# Create variable to keep track of guesses
count = 0

# Define menu for ease of reference

menu = """
1. Play Game
2. Exit
"""

choice = None

# Set the Loop

while (choice != 2):
    print (menu)
    choice = int(input("Would you like to play a game?"))

    if (choice == 1):
        print ("Guess a number between 1 & 100:")
        x = random.randint (1, 100)
        guess = int(input())

        while (guess != x):
            if (guess < x):
                guess = int(input("Your guess is too low, try again:"))
                count = count+1

            elif (guess > x):
                guess = int(input("Your guess is too high, try again:"))
                count = count+1

            elif (guess == x):
                print ("Congratulations, you guessed the number in", count, "attempts!")



    else:
        exit

#Pseudocode for the above program

# Ask user if they want to play the guessing game
# Randomly generate a number
# Ask user to guess and give hints (too low, too high)
# Generate a new random number each game
# Only quit when user selects to exit
```

'''

Answer (score 0):

When your guess is wrong (guess < x or guess >x) the program enters one of those if-blocks. There you update your guess. If that guess is then right, it will not execute the guess==x block, since the guess was wrong when it was compared with x.

Instead of asking for a new guess inside the if-else-bodies, ask for it at the beginning of the loop and check afterwards:

```
print ("Guess a number between 1 & 100:")
x = random.randint (1, 100)

while (True):
    guess = int(input())
    if (guess < x):
        print("Your guess is too low, try again:")
        count = count+1

    elif (guess > x):
        print("Your guess is too high, try again:")
        count = count+1

    elif (guess == x):
        print ("Congratulations, you guessed the number in", count, "attempts!")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you and that fixed the issue but now the game doesn't exit when I select (2) from the option menu.

Comment: It works fine for me. Did you add the break in the `guess==x` case?